# Google Cloud Engine -- kernel:NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using GCE with hierarchical VMs (installing OpenStack, so its KVM). So inside the GCE instance, I have 4 VMs. and in one of those VMs, I have 3 VMs.

Whenever the GCE VM CPU load goes above say 60%, the system gets flooded with these nasty messages. And then 50:50 chance, whether the VM recovers or gets corrupted.

Any ideas what's going on? And why the VM gets corrupted?

Thanks,

```
    Message from syslogd@xxxx at Mar 23 21:00:51 ...
    kernel: NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s

! [CPU 6/KVM:10791]
```

Comment: This issue refers to a hardware issue, could you explain which OS version are you running?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 16.04 but that's the Guest OS. The Host OS is run by GCE, and I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: Did you enable nested virtualization for the Google Cloud Comptue Instances? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances. In this post you can find a post related to your error mesage https://askubuntu.com/questions/929817/nmi-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu2-stuck-for-23s-nvidia-smi566?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Yes followed the instructions from this document. It didn't help. Opened a bug with GCP.

Comment: I ran into this "soft lockup" problem when running gzip on an 100 MB file. Worked around / solved, in that case, via `nice -n19  gzip ...`.  — Could there maybe maybe be some  way to make the 4 nested VMs more "nice", use less CPU?